# replace different variables into a single variable

Tags: notepad++, path

I have XML files with entries like this:

```
<path>D:/Shared/export/Outdoor Stage2/Outdoor Stage2_6_Images\Image_0.jpg</path>
<path>D:/Shared/export/Outdoor Stage2/Outdoor Stage2_10_Images\Image_0.jpg</path>
<path>D:/Shared/export/Outdoor Stage2/Outdoor Stage2_243_Images\Image_0.jpg</path>
```

I tried to find and replace only the Outdoor Stage2_*******_Images into one single folder like this:

```
<path>D:/Shared/export/Outdoor Stage2/Outdoor Stage_Images\Image_0.jpg</path>
```

because the `Image_0.jpg`, `Image_1.jpg`, `Image_2.jpg`, etc. are identical, although spread across different folders named numerically like that. So I want to put them into one folder because they're duplicate images.

Is it possible in Notepad++?

Comment: Thank you! Yes I should have just asked that I want to replace a few words.

I tried the answer given. Unfortunately it will affect other entries that are similar like this with an _Mesh.

D:/Shared/export/Outdoor Stage2/Outdoor Stage2_6_Mesh

I only want to affect entries such as this.

D:/Shared/export/Outdoor Stage2/Outdoor Stage2_***_Images.

If I could replace these Outdoor Stage2_***_Images into a totally different word that would be better. To make it like this.

D:/Shared/export/Outdoor Stage2/Textures\Image_0.jpg.

So replace Outdoor Stage2_***_Images into Textures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want here, but if you wish to replace all occurrences of `Outdoor Stage2_[number]_Images` to `Outdoor Stage_Images`, you can use the Search and Replace feature of Notepad++ to accomplish this.

1. Open the XML file in Notepad++ and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
2. Enter `2_[\d]+` in the **Find what** box and leave the **Replace with** box empty
3. Set **Search Mode** to `Regular Epression` and click **Replace All**